# Import package error even though it is properly installed

Tags: python, django, python-import, importerror, eventbrite

I have installed [EventBrite API](https://github.com/eventbrite/eventbrite-sdk-python) for my django application. The main purpose here is to add `event` details from the site into my database.

Since this script will run periodically I have added this into management/commands folder. See the below pic, file name is `eventbrite`

[image]

Problem is when I execute my script using `python manage.py eventbrite`, it is showing `ImportError: cannot import name Eventbrite` but I have already installed this package inside my `virtual environment`.

`pip freeze`

```
Django==1.9.2
eventbrite==3.3.3
requests==2.9.1
wheel==0.24.0
```

When I execute the same package in `Django Shell`, it is not showing any error

```
python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from eventbrite import Eventbrite
>>>
```

Could anyone tell me why it is showing an `import error` when I run the script using `python manage.py eventbrite` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might have a naming conflict between the `eventbrite` package loaded from pip, and the `eventbrite` module in your management command. How are you importing `EventBrite` from within your script? If you're doing `from eventbrite import Eventbrite`, then it will try to load it from your own module when using the project interpreter and not find the class. Easy solution would be to name your command something other than `eventbrite`.